# How to disable prettier in VSCode for a specific project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to turn off Prettier for a specific project. In order to do that I have created a `.prettierrc` with `{}` but it is not working.

I can deactivate the prettier plugin on vscode, since we have other projects, need to have that in the plugin list.

I also use ESLint in the project.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just create a `.prettierignore` file in the project with `**`

The entire codebase will be ignored for Prettier plugin.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: yes I solved the issue. Just shared the answer for knowledge sharing prepossess.

Comment: I did the same, and Prettier is still formatting code.

Comment: Turn off the default code formatter in Code

Comment: It needed to be in my project root for it to work for me

Answer (score 23):

You can also disable the extension for your current workspace.
Go to your extensions and hit the gear icon on Prettier, then select *"Disable (Workspace)"*

[image: disable prettier screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There's a shortcut for that too in VS CODE called `save without formatting` that the user can customize, that can come in handy because it's minimal effort. In my case I edited the shortcut to cmd + ctrl + shift + s